# Javascript: How do I setRequestHeader for Access-control-Allow-Origin BEFORE http.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Techies--

I've been going around in a circle, alternating between the error:

https://anyurlwithcreds.com/x?$format=JSON&$top=2. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

when the javascript looks like this:

```js
HTTPSFResponse.open("GET", "https://anyurlwithcreds.com/x?$format=JSON&$top=2", true);

HTTPSFResponse.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
HTTPSFResponse.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
HTTPSFResponse.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

...and the error :

'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

...when the code looks like this;

```js
HTTPSFResponse.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
HTTPSFResponse.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
HTTPSFResponse.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

HTTPSFResponse.open("GET", "https://anyurlwithcreds.com/x$format=JSON&$top=2", true);
```

Clearly I am missing something. Either I've misunderstood Access-Control-Allow-Origin's role as a header in CORs or perhaps there's a remote setting necessary on the site that's serving the pages? Please advise on how to solve this.

Comment: What is HTTPSFResponse ? is this making an ajax call. CORS headers are set by the server not by the client. Also from null origin message it seems that you're not running the code on a server and directly opening the html file from file system. If you put the file on some HTTP server you'll probably be able to something different.

Comment: @11thdimension, yes this is an ajax call. this is a test on my local desktop. I'll try this on a server

Comment: By server I meant domain of `https://anyurlwithcreds.com`, if you're the owner of this domain then you can modify the php or java code there to serve content with appropriate header. CORS headers are not meant to be set in Ajax call, they're sent by the server in the response

Comment: 11thdimension, thanks for the clarification.